# Taping blades onto your shoes. Is it a stupid idea or a practical one?

Tags: weapons, martial-arts

What if the shoes have blades! Imagine kicking your enemies and bleeding them to death! Is it practical though?

**First Case: A Post-Apocalyptic World with Zombies! How original!**

Guns are rare. Bullets are rarer. Guns with the right bullets are much rarer. With zombies so mindless, a bullet shot at brainless zombies is a bullet wasted. Each bullet is one less human to fight for limited resources.

The setting is urban, but any environmental take is accepted.

> While one cannot be careless against zombies, a knife and a practical experience are more than enough to fight a zombie.

Martial arts is the norm. Zombies are known to bite wrists but with your foot equipped with shoes duct-taped with a knife, slashing the zombies would be easier.

... Or is it? Is it better to use footwork and duct-taped knives rather than simply *wielding* knives?

**Second Case: Modern Day Drama.**

It was a devastating moment in your life. You caught your boyfriend cheating. It was as clear as the sun at high noon, and yet he dares to barge into your home and *provide an explanation*. He expresses emotions of guilt, worries, and... no! He's unforgivable! To think he... He... Just as you explode in anger, you suddenly remembered your shoes. It's a trendy one with a built-in knife underneath for self-defense. He's in front of you. It will only take a single kick, and he will no longer cheat you. He will say goodbye to his balls... And you've done it.

... Skipping to the main idea, is a shoe with a knife a good component to a surprise attack? Will the attack successfully land or get easily defended?

**Third Case: A Robber's Hostage**

It was your monthly salary and you have to take it from the nearest bank. Unfortunately, destiny played a prank and a robbery occurred. Your cautiousness allowed you to hide a knife at your left ankle safely. You also accidentally brought a tape. The loud noises from the siren of the police cars and the murmurs of death forced your mind to forge a stupid idea. A very stupid idea. Tape your knife into your shoe, with the blade under your heel. With noises acting as a cover to your loud tape and the robber's eyes occupying the police's action, it is a success. You waited until it was your turn, and it happened. The robber used you as a shield to his front and pointed a gun at your head. You explored your tired senses. Are the police signing me something? Am I lost hope? You're tired. You're supposed to be home, and yet you're here. You did the unthinkable, kicking in the robber's direction. Then gunshots occurred.

... a blade for kicking to your back... eh? What's your opinion?

**Fourth Case: Wildcard**

Do you have an interesting case where the concept is useful? Let's hear it out!

Comment: A-ah, the [Armed Legs](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArmedLegs) trope (TV Tropes warning)! This works well if blade is only stored in a shoe (but still a handheld blade). This _looks_ (but only looks) well in visual media if blade is permanently attached to a shoe.

Comment: *"A Post-Apocalyptic World with Zombies! How original!"* no less so than a shoe knife though // *"Imagine kicking your enemies and bleeding them to death"* zombies aren't traditionally considered to be subject to the normal debilitating effects, like death, of bleeding out, that us non-zombie types are .. so .. you really didn't think this through did you?

Comment: Tape is a pretty poor way to attach a weapon. Attaching things to your feet is also a good way to trip up. Your question seems to invite discussion, which makes it a little bit of a poor fit for stackexchange.

Comment: Use short screws to screw it into the bottom of your soles. Also remember to point the blades backwards, because otherwise you will trip on them walking forward.

Comment: Zombies don't bleed to death.

Comment: (a) You're allowed to ask one question. Although related, you're asking four questions. (b) Judging from how well actress Lotte Lenya did trying to shank Sean Connery with a shoe blade in *From Russia with Love,* I'm going to vote that it's not at all practical. But it's easy enough to test (aka, research before asking a Q), tape a butter knife to the bottom of your shoe and see how well it works.

Answer (score 6):

**Make skates.**

[image: skate]

This is a real practical reason to tape knives onto shoes.  Except I would not use tape - I would attach the 2 knives to a wooden 2x2 with bolts and then the 2x2 thru the sole of the boot with more bolts.  The 2 blade skate would be stable, like the ice skates little kids use.

You could kick people with these in a pinch.  It is an interesting question how one could attain a slashing attack with a kick.

More importantly you could make good time under your own power across frozen lakes and rivers.  You will be hard for the cannibals to catch.

Comment: +1 for completely making my day. I want a pair.

Comment: @JBH:  A whole new way to go mincing about.

Comment: This would be good for slicing pizza if the pizza was too big to lift off the floor.

Answer (score 5):

Improvised knife-shoes used by the unskilled will be a liability. Properly made ones, used by someone with specific training, are probably still worse than wielding knives in your hands, but *might* be useful as a surprise.

Duct-taping knives onto the soles of your shoes will make walking, running and kicking significantly harder. If you walk any distance on them, you'll wear through the tape and the knives will come loose when you try to kick with them. Having the knife points project beyond your toes more than about a half-inch (1 cm) is a great way to accidentally cut your own Achilles tendon.

The zombie case is a fine way to get in bad trouble. You can kick with more force than you can thrust with a hand, but the problem with knife thrusts against human-like bodies isn't lack of force - you don't need all that much force with a well-sharpened knife - but stabbing in the right place at the right instant. That's much easier with a hand. If zombies try to bite wrists, they'll try it with ankles too.

The modern day drama doesn't make much sense. Shoes with built-in knives will be treated as concealed knives under the law, which adds enough complexity that few shoe or clothes shops will want to sell them.

The hostage case comes the nearest to making sense. It is improvised moments before use, with a distraction, for a specific and predictable usage. It relies on the robber not wearing tough boots, and an un-trained back-kick connecting. It also won't take down the robber immediately, so you may well get shot anyway. It does not seem like a great idea.

Answer (score 3):

## Legs and Structure

Both men and women have large leg muscles when compared with their arms. These can generate a lot of force. Here is where I introduce you to *structure*.

Structure is this idea in martial arts that the human body has ranges of motion and positions in which they can most easily respond to attacks, launch their own attacks, and generate power. Kicking, while demonstrably more powerful than a punch, can easily "break" structure.

While kicking, you are either in the air, on the ground, or balancing on one leg. Many martial art systems would say that your structure is broken in these positions. (With the exception of wrestling-heavy systems.) That's bad, because you cannot respond to threats with maximum mobility. Especially in situations where seconds matter, *like most combat situations!*

This is my first cut at boot knives, but there is more. A knife taped to the bottom of a foot does you no favors when it comes to gripping the ground. This is, as you may guess, very important while fighting.

## Tells and Timing

Sometimes, people have tells, an action which indicates another is coming. Kicks have some **big** tells. The shifting weight, the raise of the leg, the twist of the torso... It's all warning the opponent that a kick is coming before any deadly force is generated. This is bad! Opponents can then retreat, sidestep, and otherwise counter this slow attack.

It also is important to know that there are fewer ways to assault with a foot than with a hand. Your angles are limited as well as your range. A dagger in the hand can stab and slice in multiple directions in addition to having more grips. An opponent will have fewer things to consider and therefore mount a better defense against these attacks.

Additionally, a foot won't come around to save you when grappling, but a dagger in the hand will! This argument is also true for longer weapons in general, but also here. Your leg makes the dagger a longer-reach weapon, and once they are within optimum kicking distance, which is quite small and easily crossed.

## But It's Unexpected!

That's the main advantage. But a dagger being drawn from a coat/cloak/belt can be equally surprising and deadly because, well, anything surprising can be deadly!

Comment: So what you are saying is. . .  the dagger should go *shink* out of the knee and not the foot.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bad idea.

if I had a knife I would prefer to hold it in my hands. Holding it gives way more attacking options to me. The only really viable if there were snake zombies which only attacked your feat/legs